# How to remove blue dashed line with numbers attached to it

Tags: 3d-view

I was trying to model quickly and ended mashing some keys (at the WASD end of my keyboard) and did something to create the blue line as shown in my screenshot. The line expands and contracts whenever I move the viewport and the numbers increase from 0 to XXXX as the line lengthens. What is this line and how do I remove it? Any help would be appreciated.

[image: Blue line]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like the MeasureIt addon. In the Tool Shelf (<kbd>T</kbd>), go to Display / MeasureIt Tools and click Hide.